# issues in installing UNIVA Grid Engine Execution host

Tags: grid, sungridengine

Hi I am just trying to install Univa Grid Engine Execution on a different host then master host. I just copy the master host directory to remote host on which I want to install execution host then set this directory as SGE_ROOT in bashrc of root. now when run the settigns.sh file which is copied with the directory from master hsot it gives following error
**util/arch: strings: not found** 
can any body help me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the string command installed:

```
which strings
```

Should produce:

```
/usr/bin/strings
```

If you see:

```
/usr/bin/which: no strings in ...
```

Then you need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

To install Grid Engine (including Univa Grid Engine) you need to first install on the machine that is going to be the master of your cluster.  There is an installation script/tool that comes with Grid Engine. So you can run (as root) either:

1) ./install_master
or
2) ./inst_sge -m

That installation tool will ask lots of questions, one very important question is 'list the machines you want to be exec nodes'. once you answer them the qmaster will be installed.

Now to install compute nodes you either have to share $SGE_ROOT over a shared filesystem or copy the entire $SGE_ROOT to the machines you want to add as exec machines.  Then run the exec installation script as root

1) set your $SGE_ROOT
   ./install_execd
or
2) set your $SGE_ROOT
   ./inst_sge -e

That should setup the exec node, including adding the appropriate init scripts.
You will have to do this on all exec nodes.